# postgresql what is the best way to export specific column from specific table from a DB to another

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

When I do this command :

```
SELECT language, title FROM cms_title WHERE language != 'en' AND title != 'Blog';
```

I see the pages I want to copy from a DB on the development server to the production server.

So, my aim is to dump those specific pages and then insert them in the production DB.

My question is :
Is it possible ? Is it the best practice / way of doing it ?

Thank you so much in advance for the time spent on my request.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can see 4 approaches:

**1. export that columns as `.csv` and import from it on seccond DB**

```
COPY (
    SELECT language, title FROM cms_title WHERE language != 'en' AND title != 'Blog'
) TO '/path/to/csv/cms_title_dump.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ';';
```

put that `.csv` in path accessible for destination server on that server perform importing:

```
COPY cms_title FROM '/path/to/csv/cms_title_dump.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV;
```

or \copy to use the command in psql + db

**2. dump it using `pg_dump` and restore (`pg_restore`)  on seccond DB**

dump:

```
pg_dump opencare -F c -h db_address -U db_user -p sb_port -t cms_title  -f /path/to/dump/cms_title.dump;
```

restore:

```
pg_restore -h dest_db_address -U dest_db_user -p dest_dp_port -d db_name /path/to/dump/cms_title.dump;
```

In this case you must remember that `pg_dump` performs dump of WHOLE table data. You can't choose subset of rows from table to dump. So this option is appropiate when doing table mirroring from ona DB to another.

**3. use `dblink` module for PostgreSQL to perform coss-database queries**

**4. generate `INSERT` query and execute it on seccond server:**

```
`SELECT
    'INSERT INTO cms_title(language, title) VALUES '
        || string_agg( '(' || language || ', '|| title || ')',  ',' )
        || ';'
FROM cms_title WHERE language != 'en' AND title != 'Blog';`
```

Comment: pg_restore will add what is in the file to the specific DB ? That sounds cool

Comment: You could restore to any database you like but... the tables in both source DB and destination DB should be identical (names and structure). But do you need to mirror tables or that table on destination db have some values already?

Comment: The DB are identical except for the blog. The page translated doesn't exist in prod so it should be ok.

Comment: But remember that pg_dump performs dump of WHOLE table data. You CAN'T choose subset of rows from table to dump.

Comment: Yes after reflexion I think I will choose your first exemple :) thank you Gabriel !

Comment: So I tried the first one but I have an error at 'Blog'; - it's not taking the semi column.

Comment: Ok, but waht is your error? Is `SELECT` query alone returns data successfully? And what is "semi column"?

Comment: Yes it does.
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: ...tle FROM cms_title WHERE title = 'test migration' ; ) TO STD...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95720/discussion-between-gabriels-messanger-and-jay-cee).

Comment: COPY takson FROM 'path to csv file' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;

Comment: As +Mateusz points out, a 'HEADER' is missing from the command which inserts the data into the new table. Also, if COPY does not work, just type \copy in psql

Answer (score 19):

I do it the following way:

**1.create dump:**

```
psql -h dbhost1 -d dbname -U dbuser -c "copy(SELECT language, title FROM cms_title WHERE language != 'en' AND title != 'Blog') to stdout" > dump.tsv`
```

**2.import dump:**

```
psql -h dbhost2 -d dbname -U dbuser -c 'copy cms_title from stdin' < dump.tsv
```

This will append imported data to the table.

Comment: awesome I will try it ! Thanks dude

Comment: Hey i am getting this error "relation cms_table does not exist". Any Solution?

Answer (score 0):

I usually doing like this For Import specific column dump

1. Create cms_title_dump.csv file.

   ```
   touch /home/www/html/cms_title_dump.csv
   ```
2. give the write permission

   ```
   chmoc 777 /home/www/html/cms_title_dump.csv
   ```
3. execute this query

   ```
   COPY (SELECT language, title, FROM cms_title WHERE language != 'en' AND title != 'Blog' ) to '/home/www/html/cms_title_dump.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
   ```
4. change the file permission. as Read only