# How to copy data from column to another column in dffrent database and schema?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to export specific data columns from one table to another. The first table has the following columns (in this order):

```
id, uid, name, email
```

The second table (empty) on another database, which has columns like (in this order):

```
id, email, login_token, remember_created_at, name, uid
```

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826566/postgresql-what-is-the-best-way-to-export-specific-column-from-specific-table-fr), I am doing something like:

To export:

```
docker exec -t [my-container] psql -U postgres -d [source_db_name] -c "Copy (Select id, uid, name, email From users) To STDOUT With CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';" > users.csv
```

To import:

```
cat users.csv | docker exec -i [my-container] psql -U postgres -d [target_db_name] -c "\copy users FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER ',' csv header;" < users.csv
```

I am getting this error:

```sh
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "some string from email column"
CONTEXT:  COPY users, line 2, column remember_created_at: "some string from email column"
```

This means I have a conflict in columns order. `email` value gets inserted in `remember_created_at` column.

I need a way to get the data from each column from the first table to the same column that has the same name:

```
name --> name
id   --> id
email --> email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the target columns: `... copy users(id, uid, name, email) FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER ...`.

Note that they should be listed in the same order as the file content.